# jQuery date picker

Tags: jquery, ajax, datepicker

I have the main HTML file and after the button click, it shall come from AJAX test.html

**Test.html:**

```
<div type="text" id="datepicker">
    H
</div>
```

**my.js:**

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test.html',
            success: function (data2) {

            } //end of success                                
        }); //end of ajax      

        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Main.html Ajax calls the test.html,
It needs to show the datepicker in the input field , how could I accomplish the above task?

Thank you

Comment: You may want to reformat your question because it's not too readable now. Also I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with your code and what's the relationship between date picker and AJAX.

Comment: agree with RaYell and also I think that the datepicker widget already displays the current date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are saying, ...

> I've loaded some stuff using AJAX and I want to bind stuff to it...

Then all you need to do is move your $(document).ready... stuff into a function that you can also call when an AJAX request loads. You can pass the relevant DOM tree into that function too, which will help.

Example:

```
var pageLoaded = function(htmlDocument) {
    $(".datepicker", htmlDocument).datepicker();
    $(".something").click(function() { alert("Hi"); });
};
// Page Load
$(document).ready(function() {
    pageLoaded(this);
});
```

Then when you call AJAX, you do the same...

```
$("#MyDiv").load("http://somepage/", function() { pageLoaded(this) });
```

And it applies all the page load stuff to your newly loaded AJAX bits.